# Check if array contains string, case insensitive

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I'm trying to write an application that removes words from a list of words:

```
puts "Words:"
text = gets.chomp
puts "Words to remove:"
remove = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")
removes = remove.split(" ")
words.each do |x| 
    if removes.include.upcase? x.upcase
        print "REMOVED "
    else
        print x, " "
    end
end
```

How would I make this case insensitive?
I tried putting `.upcase` in there but no luck.

Comment: In where? It's not clear what you tried.

Comment: in the if statement.
Edited the OP

Comment: Wouldn't you need to up case each element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
words.each do |x| 
    if removes.select{|i| i.downcase == x.downcase} != []
        print "REMOVED "
    else
        print x, " "
    end
end
```

`array#select` will select any element from the array if the block yields true. So if `select` do not select any element and return an empty array, it is not in the array.

---

**Edit**

You can also use `if removes.index{|i| i.downcase==x.downcase}`. It performs better than `select` since it does not create a temporary array and returns whenever it finds the first match.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts "Words:"
text = gets.chomp
puts "Words to remove:"
remove = gets.chomp
words = text.split(" ")
removes = remove.upcase.split(" ")

words.each do |x|
  if removes.include? x.upcase
    print "REMOVED "
  else
    print x, " "
  end
end
```

Comment: Not really what I expected but it works. (I prefere to keep the removes in their original casing).

Comment: then keep it normal case and instead use: `removes.any? { |r| r.upcase == x.upcase }`